# powershell - Generate SAS token for azure service bus queue/topic using New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus, sas-token

I have the below code to get the authorization ids of the Service bus and Queue separately

```
$auth_Ids = (Get-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -NamespaceName $NamespaceName).Id
$auth_Id = ($auth_Ids[1] | Out-String)
```

Running the above gives me Service Bus SAS Policy authorization Id

```
/subscriptions/XXX/resourcegroups/YYY/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/YYY-asb/authorizationrules/SASPolicy
```

Now to get the queue auth id

```
$qauth_Id = (Get-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -NamespaceName $NamespaceName -QueueName $QueueName).Id
```

Running the above gives me QUEUE SAS Policy authorization Id

```
/subscriptions/XXX/resourcegroups/YYY/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/YYY-asb/queues/qname/authorizationrules/Policy
```

Only difference between the auth_ids is `queues/qname/`

Now when I call the `New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken` to generate a SAS Token the call with queue auth_id works.

This works (qauth_id from queue)

```
$sastoken = (New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken -AuthorizationRuleId $qauth_Id -KeyType $PolicyName -ExpiryTime $endtime).SharedAccessSignature
```

This doesn't (auth_id from service bus)

```
$sastoken = (New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken -AuthorizationRuleId $auth_Id -KeyType $PolicyName -ExpiryTime $endtime).SharedAccessSignature
```

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line
> | 0, position 0.

I am not sure how to get SAS token to the service bus itself rather than the queue/topic.
Do I have to create SAS Policy on each queue or topic to get the SAS token or the SAS Policy at the service bus level is sufficient?

Comment: You have a permission issue.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/permissions-consent-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

Answer (score 0):

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line | 0, position 0.

The error may be you are passing the **`AuthorizationruleId`** Incorrect format in the **`New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken`** command.

First I tried AuthorizationruleId with the below command:

```
$auth_Ids = (Get-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRule -ResourceGroupName xxxx -NamespaceName xxxxx.Id
$auth_Id = ($auth_Ids[1])
$auth_Id
```

**Output:**

```
 /subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/sxxxxxx/authorizationrules/saspolicy
```

Now I tried with the below command to create an **`SAS`** token using the above **`auth_Id`**

**Command:**

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
$EndTime = $StartTime.AddHours(2.0)
$sastoken = (New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken -AuthorizationRuleId $auth_Id -KeyType saspolicy -ExpiryTime $EndTime).SharedAccessSignature
$sastoken
```

**Output:**

```
 sr=xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net%2f&sig=%2fl5%2f0Xl9ZAgQ1X1tm98Pb47rqFSP0wJ%2fWBlLrxh9ubA%3d&se=1698853532&skn=saspolicy
```

**Total output:**

```
PS /home/xxxx> $auth_Ids = (Get-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRule -ResourceGroupName xxxx -NamespaceName xxxx).Id
PS /home/xxxx> $auth_Id = ($auth_Ids[1])             
PS /home/xxxx> $auth_Id
/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/xxxxx/authorizationrules/saspolicy
PS /home/xxxx> $StartTime = Get-Date
PS /home/xxxx> $EndTime = $StartTime.AddHours(2.0)
PS /home/xxxx> $sastoken = (New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken -AuthorizationRuleId $auth_Id -KeyType saspolicy -ExpiryTime $EndTime).SharedAccessSignature
PS /home/xxxx> $sastoken
 sr=sxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net%2f&sig=%2fl5%2f0xxxxxxxx7rqFSP0wJ%2fWBlLrxh9ubA%3d&se=1698853532&skn=saspolicy
PS /home/xxxx>
```

[image]

The above command executes and creates the **`SAS`** token at the namespace level.

**Reference:**

[New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRuleSASToken (Az.ServiceBus) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/new-azservicebusauthorizationrulesastoken?view=azps-10.4.1)